# How do I permanently disable suspend and hibernate modes on Elementary OS 5 "Juno" 64 bit?

Tags: suspend

I installed Elementary OS 5 "Juno" 64 bit GNU/Linux on my mid-2017 AVA Direct gaming desktop PC with an ASUS ROG Crosshair VI Hero AM4 x370 chipset motherboard with an AMD Ryzen 5 1600X, ASUS ROG STRIX AMD Radeon RX Vega 64, Kingston HyperX Savage 32 GB DDR4 2,666.00 MHz DIM RAM, EVGA T2 850 watt 80+ Titanium PSU. I disabled the suspend mode permanently, but after two hours after I lock my screen and I go to sleep at night, my gaming desktop PC goes into suspend mode. When I press the power button, it resumes successfully without any problems. I would like to disable suspend and hibernate mode permanently as I prefer to keep my three gaming PCs turned on and connected to the Internet via one of my virtual private networks most of the time in my bedroom. How do I permanently disable suspend and hibernate on Elementary OS 5 "Juno" 64 bit GNU/Linux so my gaming desktop PC stays on and connected?

Comment: See this link
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16487/power-setting-doesnt-work

Answer (score 4):

1. Open up the terminal and type this in and your password:

   ```
   sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
   ```
2. Change your directory to `/etc/default`. Type in these commands:

   - `sudo cp /etc/default/acpi-support /etc/default/acpi-support.bak`
   - `sudo apt install gedit`
   - `sudo gedit /etc/default/acpi-support`
3. Look for the line `SUSPEND_METHODS=`. Type this in and save the document:

   - `SUSPEND_METHODS="none"`
     *. exit gedit
4. Restart your desktop, notebook or server to make the changes take into
   effect.

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard my previous posts; they are not technically correct.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

I did quite a bit of research so I wanted to share this information with this group if someone else may find it to be helpful or useful.

GNOME 3.28 64 bit has a software flaw in which your desktop or notebook PC will go into suspend or sleep mode after you either lock your screen or leave it at idle for twenty minutes. This means that any GNU/Linux distribution or version that uses GNOME 3.28 64 bit is affected including the older Ubuntu 18.04.x 64 bit LTS, Red Hat Fedora Workstation 28 64 bit and others that use it as well. There are separate but related fixes for GNOME 3.28 64 bit and Elementary OS 5 Juno([release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno)) 64 bit that are closely related that will solve this problem. I am going to share the solution that worked for me for Elementary OS 5 Juno([release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno)) 64 bit GNU/Linux in this post.

To fix the problem with locking your screen that causes your [ethernet](/questions/tagged/ethernet) or 802.11 [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) to disconnect after twenty minutes, follow these instructions step by step:

- Open up the terminal
- Type in `sudo -s`
- Type in your root password
- Type in `su -s /bin/bash lightdm`
- Type in `dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type`
- Type in `dbus-launch gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`
- Type in `exit`
- Type in `exit` again
- Type in `exit` once again to close the terminal

To fix the problem with your desktop or notebook PC going to sleep or suspend mode after twenty minutes:

- Open up the terminal
- Type in `dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing`
- Put in your root password
- Type `exit` to close the terminal
- Restart your desktop or notebook PC for these changes to take into effect

To verify that these two important fixes do work, I own three gaming PCs: 1. mid-2017 AVA Direct
2. mid-2017 ASUS ROG STRIX GL702ZC and
3. mid-2016 Acer Predator 17X (GX-791).

Elementary OS 5 Juno([release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno)) 64 bit GNU/Linux is installed and updated on each gaming PC not to mention a healthy list of both free and open source and third-party closed source and proprietary software products. I decided to test these solutions by connecting to VPNSecure.me to different VPN gateway servers in the United States of America and I locked my screens and I waited for thirty minutes. After that period of time elapsed, I unlocked my screens and I double checked to verify that my gaming PCs had not gone into sleep or suspend mode which they did not and that my VPN encrypted tunnels were still connected which they still are connected at this time.

Make sure to restart your desktop or notebook PCs after committing these changes in the terminal so that the changes take into effect after each PC restarts itself.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to the [post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16734/25930).

Solution in Ansible:

```
- name: Disable suspend and hibernate
  when:
    - ansible_system == 'Linux'
  become: yes
  block:
    - systemd:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        enabled: no
        masked: yes
      with_items:
        - sleep.target
        - suspend.target
        - hibernate.target
        - hybrid-sleep.target
    - replace:
        path: /etc/default/acpi-support
        regexp: '^(SUSPEND_METHODS=)[^\n]+$'
        replace: '\g<1>"none"'
        backup: yes
```